# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm attempting to create a search page, which will display the results into a Gridview, but keep getting the following error when I click the my search button: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

This is my code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim connectionString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myDbConnectionString1").ConnectionString
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()

    Dim mySQLQuery As String
    Dim vID As String

    vID = Request.QueryString("pgResults")

    mySQLQuery = "SELECT name,address,results,url FROM myTb WHERE name LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"

    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(mySQLQuery, connection)

    Dim myReader1 As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    While (myReader1.Read())

        GridView1.DataSource = myReader1
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End While

    panelBody.Visible = False
    panelSearchResults.Visible = True

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Could I get some help please?

Comment: Just a friendly warning, you should look into paramatizing your query, as in its current state is open to sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call Read() and then use a `IDataReader` as a DataSource, let DataBinding handle that. try this:

```
Dim myReader1 As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

GridView1.DataSource = myReader1
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate you pointing me into the right direction.